# How to create button in Rails app to let user modify ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, hyperlink

I want the user to click a link that will modify an ActiveRecord entry.  The record is called `feed.disabled` and the link will toggle that record between `true` and `false`. I made a helper method to determine the text for the link:

```
def disable_button(feed)
  if feed.disabled?
    return 'Enable Feed'
  else
    return 'Disable Feed'
  end
end
```

So my question is really two-fold.  Will that helper work to display the correct text in the view, and how do I get that link to modify the `feed.disabled` record to `true` or `false` depending on what the current state is?

Edit to add methods based on Dave's guide:

`feeds_controller.rb`:

```
def toggle_disabled_record
  @feed = Project.find(params[:project_id]).feeds.find(params[:id])
  @feed.toggle!(:disabled)
  render :nothing => true
end
```

`projects->show.html.erb`:

```
<%= link_to toggle_disable_button(feed), toggle_disabled_record_project_feed_path(feed) %>
```

`routes.rb`:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :feeds
end

resources :feeds do
  resources :xml_fields
  get toggle_disabled_record, :on => :member
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at (my) [this blog post](http://buckybits.blogspot.com/2011/09/simple-ajax-property-toggle-in-rails-30.html); it's a link, not a button, but more or less directly addresses this.

Comment: I followed your post almost verbatim, but I keep getting a routing undefined method error. I've never really understood how routing works, but the way I have my records arranged is Project has_many Feeds.  I pasted the methods I added above.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `toggle!`? I don't know what your routes are, or what link you're trying to use, so it's tough to help :)

Comment: Sorry, I was slow posting the updated methods - check them now.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use a nested resource path but defining the path in `resources :feeds` -- do a `rake routes` to see what the toggling path is.

Comment: The error lists: `undefined local variable or method toggle_disabled_record' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x00000102cfbbf8>`. I've tried putting it under the Projects resources and Feed resources to no avail.

Comment: That's because it's not in quotes in the route file; you can't directly reference a method like that in there. My two go-to guides to routing are [this](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and [this](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/).

Comment: Oh I see. I was confused because your blog example doesn't have quotes in it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It does now :-p Thanks for pointing it out; nothing worse than tutorials that don't work.

Answer (score 1):

The helper will work, but its name gives the idea that it would return the actual button element.

You could probably generate such a button using [button_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) with a helper looking something like this:

```
def toggle_disable_button(feed)
  button_text = feed.disabled? ? 'Enable feed' : 'Disable feed'

  button_to(button_text, toggle_feed_disabled_path(feed))
end
```

This is of course dependent on that you have a matching controller action and route.
You might also be able to create a button like this:

```
button_tag(button_text, :name => 'feed[disabled]', :value => !feed.disabled?)
```

but this might not work in all browsers.

Comment: I had a mistake in my title, and meant to put 'link' instead of 'button'.  I assume I could just sub `link_to` where you suggest `button_to`.  As for a controller action, I actually just wrote another helper method (I added above).

Comment: You could use a `link_to`, but that way you'd really want to give it a `:method => :put` (or `:post`). Documentation and examples for `link_to` live (for example) here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Comment: Though I realize now that that second helper won't work with your suggestion.